# ArangoDB : how to do a shortest_path filtering on edges

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

I'm using ArangoDB 3.0 and I want to create an AQL query to get the shortest path from A to B, with depth = 3, filtering on some edge properties.

The "ArangoDB 2.0" version of the query, would like be the following:

```
FOR e IN GRAPH_SHORTEST_PATH('CityGraph', 'city/rome', 'city/turin',
  { 
    edgeExamples: [{filterProperty: 'FIRST'}, {filterProperty: 'SECOND' }]} 
  )
```

I read the documentation about arangoDB 3.0, and it says:

> Conditional shortest path
>
> The SHORTEST_PATH computation will only find an unconditioned shortest
> path. With this construct it is not possible to define a condition
> like: "Find the shortest path where all edges are of type X". **If you
> want to do this, use a normal Traversal instead with the option {bfs:
> true} in combination with LIMIT 1**.

So, can someone tell me what type of AQL query I can do it?
According with the suggestions, I write this:

> FOR n, e IN 1..3 ANY 'city/rome' GRAPH 'CityGraph' OPTIONS {bfs:
> true}
> FILTER e.filterProperty IN ['FIRST', 'SECOND']
> LIMIT 1
> return {n, e}

But it returns only the first level of graph depth, instead of a depth of n.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Daniele

Answer (score 2):

with `LIMIT 1` you specify to limit the result set of your AQL to just get the shortest path.

The translation of the above query should look like this:

```
FOR n, e, p IN 1..3 ANY 'city/rome'
    GRAPH 'CityGraph'
    OPTIONS {bfs: true}
    FILTER p.edges[*].filterProperty ALL IN ['FIRST', 'SECOND']
    FILTER n._key == 'turin'
    LIMIT 1
  RETURN {n, e}
```

- you filter all edges to have a filterProperty of either `FIRST` or `SECOND`, if an edge without one of those two is passed, this path is discarded.
- the end node of the shortest path is `turin`.

Comment: I see about the `LIMIT 1`, but it is written in the documentation. 
At the contrary, I want to know the path between startNode - endNode, in the same way I do with the old GRAPH_SHORTEST_PATH.

Comment: Hi @DanieleBortoluzzi , I've modified the content of the answer to actually match your question. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Anyone know whether you can you use this construct with the "weight" parameter found in the AQL Shortest Path?

Comment: No, combining the shortest path weight parameter with LIMIT currently doesn't do anything usefull.